# How to access maven -Dexec.args arguments from Java class

Tags: java, maven

I am passing below arguments from command line and want them to be accessed in my java file. Any pseudo code will be highly helpful

```
mvn clean package exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.test.trial.properties.Main" -Dexec.args="classpath:resources/jdbc.properties file:///tmp/system.properties http://localhost:8080/global.properties"
```

When my Main class is called, want three properties file to be loaded in my Main Class.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {

   try{
       ##########what code should be here to access three argumets passed with maven command################
       System.out.println("here - " + args[0]) ;

 }
```

your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `System.getProperty("exec.args")` to get any environment variable set on command line with the flag -D

You can also configure the specific `exec.arguments` parameter of maven exec plugin to get these arguments directly into your main method. See documentation of the plugin here: http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html

Answer (score 1):

This is easily configurable as part of the plugin configuration in the build section of the `pom.xml`

Here's an example:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${exec-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable>java</executable>
                 <arguments>
                        <argument>-Dmyproperty=myvalue</argument>
                        <argument>-classpath</argument>
                        <classpath />
                        <argument>com.MyMainClass</argument>
                        <argument>-a</argument>
                        <argument>${argumentA}</argument>        
                    </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: that is fine. but how to refer to it in Java. I have passed three space separated values as arg0  arg1  arg2 in maven command. How can I access that in my java main class. A sample code will be life saver.